# Margin period of risk and scaling (MPoR)

Tags: variance, credit-risk, expected-value, exposure

I'm analyzing the formula to approximate the Margin Period of Risk (MPoR) for linearly linearly decreasing to zero exposure.

Given the MPoR at $\tau$ one can evaluate the continious total exposure at
$$\int\limits_0^{\tau} \frac{\tau - u}{\tau} du = \frac{\tau}{2}.$$

So, the MPoR for linearly decreasing exposure is half the constant one (makes sense so far).

However, then there is discrete approximation as of Var as:
$$\left[\left(1 - \frac1n \right)^2 + \left(1 - \frac2n \right)^2 + ... + \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^2   \right] = \frac n3 \left(1 - \frac1n \right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{2n} \right).$$

I've calculate the Var for $f(x) = 1 - \dfrac{u}{\tau}$:

- $\mathbb{E}(u) = \frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{u^3}{3\tau}$
- $\mathbb{E}(u^2) = \frac{u^3}{3} - \frac{u^4}{3\tau}$
- $\mathbb{Var}(u) = \frac{u^3}{3} - \frac{u^4}{3\tau} - \frac{u^4}{4} + \frac{u^5}{3\tau} - \frac{u^6}{6\tau ^2}$.

How can the approximation be obtained? it does not seem to be some simply Taylor series approximation.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you please provide a bit background to your question, i.e. the source you are referencing?

Comment: Hey @kermittfrog, it's [Chapter 7 Appendix](https://cvacentral.com/books/credit-value-adjustment/appendices/) to Jon Gregory “The xVA Challenge” 4th edition. The chapter is about margining and its credit risk assessment.